# Code::Blocks crashes after 'adding files recursively' to an empty project

Tags: linux, git, crash, ubuntu-14.04, codeblocks

I am trying to navigate the Linux kernel using the Code::Blocks IDE. The steps I used were -

1. Got the linux kernel source code from the git repo. The code is in a folder called Linux.
2. I created a new 'empty project' in Code::Blocks and saved the .cbp in a folder under the Linux directory.
3. Selected the option 'Add files recursively' for the new project.
4. Selected all the folders/files from the Linux src root.
5. Selected the target as Debug.

Code::Blocks successfully added all the files to the new project. But within a matter of minutes the GUI stops responding and finally ends up quitting. On restarting, I do not see the project and the added files. I ended up having to do the same steps again which ended up crashing again.

I am running Code::Blocks 13.12 on Ubuntu-64bit 14.04.

Is it because the Linux kernel source tree is too big? Or the files are too big?
How can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem when I started learning code blocks.The solution to this issue is 
           Go to 'Plugins' -> 'Manage Plugins' -> 'Code Completion' and
make this 'Code Completion' option 'Disable'.
Now the Code Blocks will work fine (I guess).